# Can't test changes to the database through Django Test

Tags: django, database, testing

I'm trying to write test for my first Django app and I can't seem to test changes made to the database, when I go through a view. Here's an example of one of my test.

```
def test_vote(self):
    self.set_up() 
    idea = Idea.objects.get(title="Hello people")
    c = Client()
    c.login(email="xxxxx@case.edu", password="baxter")
    r = c.post(reverse("ideas:up_vote", kwargs={'pk':idea.pk}), follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(r.status_code, 200)
    self.assertEqual(idea.votes, 1)
```

The view is suppose to up_vote an idea object, it's a simple view.

```
def like_view(request, **kwargs):
  idea = Idea.objects.get(pk = kwargs['pk'])
  idea.votes += 1
  idea.save()

  return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ideas:list'))
```

I'm using an SQLite3 database.

```
if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
         }
     } 
 else:
     DATABASES = {
         'default': {
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
              'NAME': 'django',
              'USER': env('RDS_USERNAME'),
              'PASSWORD': env('RDS_PASSWORD'),
              'HOST': env('RDS_HOST'),
              'PORT': '5432',
         }
      }
```

DEBUG = True also. Every time I run the test nothing it says idea.votes = 0 instead of 1 which is what I'm trying to get. I'm not sure if I'm just going about testing this all wrong or what. Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refresh the vote instance you have in your test method after calling the view.

```
idea = Idea.objects.get(pk=idea.pk)
self.assertEqual(idea.votes, 1)
```